# popover view for a status item not responsive to mouse movements

Tags: swift, macos, webview, nsstatusitem, nspopover

I have been struggling with this and could not find a solution.
I am creating a statusitem app for mac osx using swift. When the item is clicked a popover with a custom view that has a webview in it appears. everything works fine except that after clicking outside and the popover is closed and clicking again on statusitem to show popover this time the view (webview) is not responsive to mouse movement events like mouse hover a link etc.. unless I click inside the popover to activate it. I found a solution by calling `NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)` but this greys out other opened applications like chrome.
Now my question is that, can I make the app active without greying out other apps? dropbox mac app is an example, clicking the item in status bar, opens the popover of dropbox and its responsive to mouse events but other opened apps in the background are not greyed out and they are responsive to mouse movement events, even after clicking inside it doesn't grey out other apps unless a window appear e.g. preferences window or login window. How to achieve this behaviour?

this image shows how webview is not interactive with mouse
[image]

the second image show how it is interactive with mouse hover effect on "Advertising Programs" but chrome app is greyed out
[image]